# MVC 5 ASP.NET Identity - CreateAsync invalid user id

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I have two websites using one database, I use asp.net identity (2.2.1.40403) and I have a problem I can't understand. Now, this is a third time this happened and I have no idea where the problem can be.

I have a register and send email method like this

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new User { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, RegisterDate = DateTime.Now };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            await SendConfirmationEmail(user);

            return View("ConfirmationEmailSent");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}

private async Task SendConfirmationEmail(Dal.Models.User user)
{
    // Send an email with this link
    string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Potvrzení Vašeho účtu", "Prosím potvrďte svou emailovou adresu kliknutím <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">zde</a>.");
}
```

What happened is  that when user registered he received URL when userId was set to `3d847c51-7217-49fe-ae9d-d8e46e291559`, but in database the user was created with `95789d6e-b66e-4c9e-8ee4-fe384b82e838`. I don't understand how this can happen. By the way there is no user in database with Id `3d847c51-7217-49fe-ae9d-d8e46e291559`. Do you have any idea why and how this can happen?

Comment: What happened if you specifically query for the same user by his username instead using newly created `user`?

Comment: I've implemented that just now, this is happening uniquely so I cannot simulate it. Don't know, waiting for the log.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest calling back the user by an identifier after create was successful to make sure the properties match up.

```
//...other code removed for brevity

var user = new User { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, RegisterDate = DateTime.Now };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    //pick one
    //user = await UserManager.FindById(user.Id);
    //user = await UserManager.FindByName(user.UserName);
    user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(user.Email);

    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
    await SendConfirmationEmail(user);

    return View("ConfirmationEmailSent");
}
AddErrors(result);
```

//...other code removed for brevity

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I understand that I can do workarround like so but I would like to understand how is that possible.

Comment: @Teamol, At this stage in the life of that framework I can only assume that it was a bug in that version. Possible it could be associated with the async implementation. Would have to take a look at the source code for that version. Found an issue about create async calling in the wrong order https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2518

Answer (score 0):

I am also suspect that issue is related to `UserManager.CreateAsync()` method. You are using correctly. I will rather use manually generated user id instead generated by `UserManager`.

In your case will be:

```
    var user = new User { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, RegisterDate = DateTime.Now };
    user.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {             
         await SendConfirmationEmail(user);

         return View("ConfirmationEmailSent");
    }
```